# Incompatible types: PWideChar and TCaption

Tags: delphi

preciso resolver isso e não consigo, eu tenho uma variável que carrega uma DLL com LOADLIBRARY, quando coloco o caminho que está a DLL (que fica dentro de um edit) ele da o erro acima do tópico.

ERRO: **Incompatible types: PWideChar and TCaption**

Estou usando da seguinte forma:

```
libw := LoadLibrary(Edit5.Text + 'teste.dll');
```

Aonde Edit5.Text (é o caminho aonde a DLL está). Alguma ideia ?

Grato!

Comment: tente com `libw := LoadLibrary(StringToWideChar(Edit5.Text + 'teste.dll'));`

Comment: @MarcosRegis, deu esse erro: E2035 Not enough actual parameters

Comment: libw é uma variável de que tipo ?

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, do tipo "cardinal".

Comment: @user7605, existe algum motivo para que a libw seja Cardial ? Aproveite e teste isto: libw := LoadLibrary(StringToOleStr(Edit1.Text + 'Project1.dll'));

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, perfeito deu certo rs. Sobre o CARDIAL foi pesquisando na internet mesmo, nada em especial pq ? Coloque como resposta para eu poder pontuar você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aproveite e teste isto:

```
libw := LoadLibrary(StringToOleStr(Edit1.Text + 'Project1.dll'));
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/String_Types_(Delphi)#Mixing_Delphi_Strings_and_Null-Terminated_Strings), a forma correta de fazer isso é a seguinte:

```
LoadLibrary(PChar(Edit5.Text + 'teste.dll'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use assim

```
var
  wc : array[0..1024] of WideChar;
  path : String;

begin
  // (...) Outros codigos
  path := Edit5.Text + 'teste.dll';
  StringToWideChar(path, wc, Length(path));
  LoadLibrary(wc);
end;
```

Comment: não deu certo. Veja o código de TESTE completo se eu deixo no mesmo diretório funciona perfeitamente: http://pastebin.com/3iSrTPsH

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo :
Imagina que na dll tem a seguinte função:

```html
function Somar(a, b: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
 Result := a + b; // retorna a soma
end;
```

```html
//fazendo a leitura de uma dll

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
 // vamos declarar um tipo function
  TSomarFuncao = function(a, b: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
var
  Somar: TSomarFuncao; // uma variável que representará a função
  DLLHandle: THandle; // este é o handle para a DLL
begin
  // vamos carregar a DLL
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('ItamarMinhaDLL.dll');
  try
    // vamos obter o endereço da função na DLL
    Somar := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'Somar');

    // vamos chamar a função agora
    if Assigned(Somar) then
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(Somar(4, 3)))
    else
      ShowMessage('Não foi possível chamar a rotina desejada');
  finally
    FreeLibrary(DLLHandle); // vamos liberar a DLL
  end;

end;
```